# LED turning on late

Tags: esp8266, arduino-nano

I am using an Arduino nano and an ESP8266. I have burnt an Arduino, but when I send a request to the Arduino LED, it takes some time to turn ON.

Here is my code:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial esp8266(2,3); //Pin 2 & 3 of Arduino as RX and TX. Connect TX and RX of ESP8266 respectively.
#define DEBUG true
#define led_pin 11 //LED is connected to Pin 11 of Arduino
#define LED1 6
#define LED2 7
#define LED3 4
#define LED4 5

void setup()
  {
    pinMode(led_pin, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(led_pin, LOW);
     pinMode(LED1,OUTPUT);
 pinMode(LED2,OUTPUT);
 pinMode(LED3,OUTPUT);
 pinMode(LED4,OUTPUT);
    Serial.begin(115200);
    esp8266.begin(115200); //Baud rate for communicating with ESP8266. Your's might be different.
    esp8266Serial("AT+RST\r\n", 5000, DEBUG); // Reset the ESP8266
    esp8266Serial("AT+CWMODE=1\r\n", 5000, DEBUG); //Set station mode Operation
    esp8266Serial("AT+CWJAP=\"shubham\",\"shubh@1\"\r\n", 5000, DEBUG);//Enter your WiFi network's SSID and Password.

    //while(!esp8266.find("OK")) 
    //{
     //}
    esp8266Serial("AT+CIFSR\r\n", 5000, DEBUG);
     esp8266Serial("AT+CIFSR\r\n", 5000, DEBUG);
      esp8266Serial("AT+CIFSR\r\n", 5000, DEBUG);//You will get the IP Address of the ESP8266 from this command. 
    esp8266Serial("AT+CIPMUX=1\r\n", 5000, DEBUG);
    esp8266Serial("AT+CIPSERVER=1,80\r\n", 5000, DEBUG);
  }

void loop()
  {
   String IncomingString="";
 boolean StringReady = false;

 while (esp8266.available()){
   IncomingString=esp8266.readString();
   StringReady= true;
  }

  if (StringReady){
    Serial.println("Received String: " + IncomingString);

  if (IncomingString.indexOf("LED1=ON") != -1) {
    digitalWrite(LED1,HIGH);


   }

  if (IncomingString.indexOf("LED1=OFF") != -1) {
    digitalWrite(LED1,LOW);

   }

     if (IncomingString.indexOf("LED2=ON") != -1) {
    digitalWrite(LED2,HIGH);
   }

  if (IncomingString.indexOf("LED2=OFF") != -1) {
    digitalWrite(LED2,LOW);
   }

     if (IncomingString.indexOf("LED3=ON") != -1) {
    digitalWrite(LED3,HIGH);
   }

  if (IncomingString.indexOf("LED3=OFF") != -1) {
    digitalWrite(LED3,LOW);
   }

  if (IncomingString.indexOf("LED4=ON") != -1) {
    digitalWrite(LED4,HIGH);
   }

  if (IncomingString.indexOf("LED4=OFF") != -1) {
    digitalWrite(LED4,LOW);
   }

  }
 }


String esp8266Serial(String command, const int timeout, boolean debug)
  {
    String response = "";
    esp8266.print(command);
    long int time = millis();
    while ( (time + timeout) / millis())
      {
        while (esp8266.available())
          {
            char c = esp8266.read();
            response += c;
          }
      }
    if (debug)
      {
        Serial.print(response);
      }
    return response;
  }
```

Comment: Try changing the `while` to an `if`.

Comment: change `while` to `if` and use `esp8266.readStringUntil('\n');` `esp8266.readString();` has a 1 second timeout after the last received character (because it doesn't know it was the last). https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/readstringuntil/